# Can i use function based formatting of labels for Y axis with Angular Google chart?

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

In a project i'm using Angular Google charts http://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/.

I've encountered a problem that one cannot use function based formatting of labels on Y axis (vAxis object in configuration). That means i need  to do something like:

```
       "vAxis": {
            format: function(value){
                return $filter('customFilter')(value)
        }
    }
```

but there is no option.
Can anyone tell me what is a workaround?

Comment: to clarify, you're not looking for something like --> `vAxis: {format: '#,##0.00'}` ? -- also, if what you need isn't available that way, you can modify the chart, once the 'ready' event has fired -- [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35848832/5090771)

Comment: Nope. I want to apply angular filter to every label